# How to redirect link of old domain to new domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, migration

I transfer my client's CMS from a domain to another domain. I also change the directory where CMS was installed. CMS in old domain was installed in client's subdirectory and in new domain is in wwwroot. I would like not to make this migration difficult for customers and I thought of using an `.htaccess` file to be inserted in the root of the old domain to redirect to the new one. In particular, I would like if (for example) a customer clicks on a link sent to him via email from the CMS again when he was pointing to the old domain, he would be redirected to the same page as the new domain. For example, if in the customer's email there was a link such as

```
https://olddomain.example/clients/viewinvoice.php?id=447
```

will be redirected to

```
https://newdomain.example/viewinvoice.php?id=447
```

How could this be done? I tried with:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /
    
RewriteRule ^clients(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.example/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: _"What do you suggest me?"_ - that you go inform yourself about the basics, and then make an attempt yourself. [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/1427878)

Comment: @lizzus Nice. I think your conf just needs `[L,QSA,R=301]` instead of `[L,R=301]` to work. The QSA flag appends the query string. Also, what happens with your tried config?

Comment: Great! I changed [L,QSA,R=301] instead of [L,R=301] and works! Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clients/$1 [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Use the above file as .htaccess file and upload in the root folder

Comment: but this suppose you use the same domain and change only directory. I need to move from old domain_name/clients to new_domain_name

Answer (score 0):

Solved like indicated from @example-person

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /
    
RewriteRule ^clients(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.example/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```